# Is there a difference between heating a liquid from above and heating a solid?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, convection

If you were to heat a container full of liquid from the top, would it behave the same as a solid being heated in the same fashion? (Assuming both the liquid and the solid have the same thermal conductivity).

By heating the container from the top I would think you would eliminate convection, and therefore make the liquid heat up the same as a solid I.E. mainly through conduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there would be no natural convection in this case.

Unless you had something external to the heat source to disturb the liquid, it would remain stagnant and the heat transfer would be conductive

The same thing happens when you try and cool something from the bottom (unless it's liquid water near freezing or has similar non-standard properties).

Comment: +1 To add to the answer: If you did a real life experiment, you may very well find convection even when heated from above, if the container walls are more conducting than liquid and therefore can transfer heat to the bottom of the liquid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , heat will transfer through conduction like in solids. But  how fast it will heat will also depends on surface area , initial temperature besides thermal conductivity.